# Java anonymous classes and Garbage Collector

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, anonymous-class

Lets assume that some class is not reachable, but there are another **anonymous** classes generated by the class which are reachable. Could the first one be removed by the Garbage Collector?

Example:

```
class Outer {
  public Object getInner() {
    return new Object() {};
  }
}

...

Outer outer = new Outer();
Object inner = outer.getInner();

// Could the "outer" instance be removed here considering that "inner" is using below?
```

Comment: In your code you are calling a method from the `Outer` class. What can possibly be unreachable there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the outer instance is still reachable in this case, since every non-static inner class has an implicit rerefence to its outer class instance.

Comment: The difference is that anonymous class in my example does not use its reference to the outer class explicitly(neither internally nor externally). So I think that actually outer class is not reachable.

Comment: It still has the reference. And the JVM is unable to know that this reference will never be used. If you never use this outer reference, the class should be a static inner class, or a top-level class.